# SSIS datetime to datetime migration error

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I have simple (I thought) task to migrate table from db1 to db2 and stuck on this error which looks like about datetime. I completely lost: here is what I have:
Msg.

```
[9 LAB_IN [2]] Error: There was an error with 9 TABLE_OUT.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output].Columns[SCR_DATE] on 9 TABLE_OUT.Outputs[OLE DB Source Output]. The column status returned was: "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
```

My  source and target column ddl is same:

```
Column_name Type    Computed    Length
SCR_DATE    datetime    no  8
SCR_DATE    datetime    no  8
```

No null or garbage in source: this return nothing

```
SELECT TOP 10 SCR_DATE, LEN(SCR_DATE), * 
 FROM table_IN
 WHERE LEN(SCR_DATE) <> 19  OR  SCR_DATE IS nuLL
```

so it's page encoding??  this also looks same.

```
Source:  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
Target:  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

In my package I just have have ole-db source and destination

I'm on:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.5058.0 (X64)
```

What I'm missing here?
Thanks. Mario

P.S

THen after playing I got this error in derived column box:

```
   Error at 9 Error at 9 Lab_IN [Derived Column [2]]: The function "SUBSTRING" does not support the data type "DT_DBTIMESTAMP" for parameter number 1. The type of the parameter could not be implicitly cast into a compatible type for the function. To perform this operation, the operand needs to be explicitly cast with a cast operator.
```

Comment: Further playing I got this message: after trying to do format:

Comment: Are these databases on two different servers? If so, are these servers linked?

Comment: So the error occurs at the OLE DB Source? You mentioned using a derived column as well. Is it possible to upload some screenshots of your data flow with the properties for the relevant components?

Comment: Tx, all . I made brand new pack on other machine it worked!!??   I think I need to learn how to refresh all my connections? Or... something else is happened...